# Java Swing; is there a way when clicking a button, a popup will appear NEXT TO THAT BUTTON

Tags: java, swing

I have a JButton that has a callback function like so:

```
myJButtonCallBackFunc (ActEvtListener evt) {
    myFrame.pack();
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The myFrame pops up on the upper left hand corner of the screen.  My question: is there a property that controls where the pop up pops up?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window.setLocationRelativeTo(Component)

Comment: perfect! exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If myFrame extends component there is the [setLocation(int x, int y)][1] method.

There is also the [setLocationRelativeTo( Component c )](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo(java.awt.Component)) method.

[1]: http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation(int, int)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location of the button using the [getLocationOnScreen](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen()) method and then use the [setLocation][2] to set the position of the JFrame

[2]: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation(int, int)